# How to make a currency shop using mongodb and discord.js

Tags: javascript, mongodb, discord.js

I'm trying to make a adventure discord bot I have programmed many commands and I have also created a currency and ways to make money but I don't have a way to spend the money except to pay so you don't get in prison. I want to make a store where you can buy items and other stuff. I haven't written any code for that because I have no idea of what to do and how to do it. If anyone knows please reply.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free code writing service. You should first attempt at coding the command by yourself and then come here as a **last result**.

Answer (score 0):

In your pay command, you clearly have a function that takes away some amount of money, right?

So you can just make a simple pagintated embed with discord pagination, or something like that, I forgot how to spell it, and then just list the pricing. That's your shop command.

Then make the buy command. You then check whats after the buy command, for example, I recommend adding something like IDS to the items in your shop, and the listing it near the item or in its description in the embed, and then when a user uses the buy command, check what ID is after it.

If there's simply nothing, or you didn't find the id in your args, then simply return an embed saying the item was not found, please use (prefix) shop command.

Then if the user does mention an item, then take away the amount of money from the database with that function from the pay command, and then just simply load the item into the users database inventory. :)